# REST (GET) Service fails on certain Encrypted IDs

Tags: apex, rest, encryption

I have the following REST service that allows you to return data based off an ID. These ID's are encrypted from a external system we control, and when I call it through workbench using 2 different ID's I get failing results on one of the ID's

Through workbench

```
/services/apexrest/RegisteredUser/v0/encryptedID/preferences/notifications/

MLvRbIDaF+0weUzjrRSK0Q== (This one works)
WXR+YAXyqzmKtxM0G1acWw== (This one works)

iuhXVpOx^aYQvLeUPbtiCw== (This one doesn't with a response of 
[ {
"errorCode" : "BAD_REQUEST",
"message" : "Invalid URL specified"
} ])
```

The following is the REST(GET) of my service

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/RegisteredUser/v0/*')
global with sharing class REST_RegisteredUser
{   
// -------- Constants --------
// Request types for getting / updating
global static final String PREFERENCES_NOTIFICATIONS = '/preferences/notifications';

// -------- Variables --------
// Response handler
 global static REST_RegisteredUserResponse processResults = new REST_RegisteredUserResponse();


// -------- Methods --------    
// get parameters
@HttpGet
global static void getRegisteredUser()
{
    Diagnostics.push('getRegisteredUser');

    RestRequest request = RestContext.request;
    RestResponse response = RestContext.response;

    InnerClasses.ValidateRegistedUserURI confirmURI = validateURI(request.requestURI);

    if(confirmURI.isValid)
    {
        if(confirmURI.dataType == PREFERENCES_NOTIFICATIONS)
        {
            response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(processResults.getRegisteredUserByEncryptedID(confirmURI.encryptedDryFlyID)));
            response.statusCode = processResults.transactionStatusCode;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(processResults.throwError(processResults.parameters, 'getRegisteredUser', 400)));
        response.statusCode = 400;
    }

    Diagnostics.pop();
}

// Validate the URI and payload for acting upon type and methods
private static InnerClasses.ValidateRegistedUserURI validateURI(String uri)
{
    InnerClasses.ValidateRegistedUserURI result = new InnerClasses.ValidateRegistedUserURI();

    try
    {
        if(uri.contains(PREFERENCES_NOTIFICATIONS))
        {
            System.debug('URIII ' + uri);
            result.dataType = PREFERENCES_NOTIFICATIONS;
            result.encryptedDryFlyID = uri.substring(uri.indexOf('v0/') + 3, uri.indexOf(result.dataType));
            System.debug('gkjgjg ' + uri.substring(uri.indexOf('v0/') + 3, uri.indexOf(result.dataType)));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception error)
    {
        // ignored, invalid uri
    }

    System.debug('result ' + result);

    result.isValid = (result.dataType == null) ? false : true;
    return result;
}
```

So I'm wondering, is their a special character in encryptedID that is not allowed to be passed to SFDC?  It appears it doesn't like the `^` does anyone know why this may cause issues?

Comment: Your data is being converted to Base64. Base64 only uses a-z, A-Z, 0-9, +, /, and =. You shouldn't be getting any other characters in your value.

Comment: So this is something I will need to correct in my external system when they send me the encryptedID then?

Comment: Granted, I could be wrong, but I think it's a good first guess. Alternatively, it should be noted that ^ is an "unsafe character" and must be URL-encoded.